# how to access livesdk offline in android (skydrive)

Tags: onedrive

working on app for android

in which using livesdk (for android) provided by microsoft to access skydrive on device

the problem is out to work offline???

how to initialize LiveConnectClient in that case

really needed help

ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

The LiveSDKs and OneDrive-APIs are not meant to function offline as they require connectivity to their service components to retrieve data.

If you are looking to use the data retrieved by the LiveSDK while the client is not connected to the internet I would recommend coming up with an appropriate caching scheme so your application has the data it needs on hand.

When your application comes back online, you can synchronize its state with the [view.changes](http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm) to start the reconciling process.